# GitHub API v3 - get last N commits by user on project

Tags: api, github, github-api

I'm looking for a way to get the latest N (say 10) commits (the commit messages and time of commit would be enough) a user made on a specific project (repo)? Is there any way to do this with the GitHub API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub api to obtain last N number of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36688853/github-api-to-obtain-last-n-number-of-commits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub commits API does not currently support filtering by a specific author or committer login/e-mail address.

Comment: Is enough info returned for the user of the API to to filter the results after retrieving them?