# GitHub api to obtain last N number of commits

Tags: github, github-api

Is it possible to obtain last N number of commits to a particular branch in a GitHub repository using GitHub API ?

I just found few GitHub api details regarding the commits [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/), but none of them are giving details about last N number of commits!

Anyone can provide a better idea about this ?

Also, Is it possible to identify the changed file type during the last commit from a user ?

Comment: Did you try [pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination/#changing-the-number-of-items-received)? You can limit items per page with it.

Comment: @Andrew : Thanks a lot for the solution ! But only issue with this solution is that, what ever I am getting is from the top of the list. i.e it's not the last N number of commits. Here is the command which I have tried, `curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/fantomex/commits?per_page=2`   ... Is there any option to sort the list of commits that we get from this api ?

Comment: Pay attention to [parameters](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository). `sha: SHA or branch to start listing commits from. Default: the repository’s default branch (usually master).` You can try URL `https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/fantomex/commits?per_page=2&sha=branch_name` to retrieve only related commits.

Comment: I found the parameter for both **sorting & order** also. I have modified my previous query according to the latest change :  `curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/technoweenie/fantomex/commits?sort=created&order=desc`  .. But it's still showing the same output itself..! Is there any fault in this ?? I got the details about Sorting & ordering from [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/)

Comment: Have you tried url from my previous comment? Is it still not what you want?

Comment: Yes..Thank you ! That's it.. :) I just forgot to check the date of the commits..By default it was in descending order. I was only trying to cross check the commit id & it was same in both cases .. Sorry for that !  Also, do you have any idea about the second section in my question ? i.e how to identify the changed file type during the last commit of the user ?I thought, this details will be available from the output that obtained from the previous API.. But the file /  file type details are not there in it's output !

Comment: Commits listing returns only some meta-information about commits. If you want to see details, you must perform another request to [get a single commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit). See the 'files' item in example.

Comment: @Andrew: Thank you for your continuous support ! Your comments were pretty good enough to solve all my issues related to this question :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#commits) to get the last N number of commits,

**INPUT:**

```
GIT_REPO="https://api.github.com/repos/kubernetes/kubernetes" # Input Git Repo
BRANCH_NAME="master"                                          # Input Branch Name
COMMITS_NUM="5"                                               # Input to get last "N" number of commits

curl --silent --insecure --request GET --header "Accept: application/vnd.github.inertia-preview+json" "$GIT_REPO/commits?sha=$BRANCH_NAME&page=1&per_page=1000" | jq --raw-output '.[] | "\(.sha)|\(.commit.author.date)|\(.commit.message)|\(.commit.author.name)|\(.commit.author.email)" | gsub("[\n\t]"; "")' | awk 'NF' | awk '{$1=$1;print}' | head -$COMMITS_NUM
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
COMMIT_ID|DATE/TIME|COMMIT_MESSAGE|AUTHOR_NAME|AUTHOR_EMAIL
5ed4b76a03b5eddc62939a1569b61532b4a06a72|2020-11-26T15:24:19Z|Merge pull request #96421 from dgrisonnet/fix-apiservice-availabilityFix aggregator_unavailable_apiservice gauge|Kubernetes Prow Robot|k8s-ci-robot@users.noreply.github.com
c1f36fa6f28d3618c03b65799bc3f58007624e5f|2020-11-25T06:32:41Z|Merge pull request #96829 from songjiaxun/azuredisk_api_versionfix: change disk client API version for Azure Stack|Kubernetes Prow Robot|k8s-ci-robot@users.noreply.github.com
c678434623be4957d892a9865e5649f887a40c49|2020-11-24T21:20:39Z|Merge pull request #96831 from bobbypage/vendor-cadvisor-v0_38_5vendor: update cAdvisor to v0.38.5|Kubernetes Prow Robot|k8s-ci-robot@users.noreply.github.com
c652ffbe4a29143623a1aaec39f745575f7e43ad|2020-11-24T14:59:01Z|Merge pull request #96636 from Nordix/disable-nodeport-2service.spec.AllocateLoadBalancerNodePorts followup|Kubernetes Prow Robot|k8s-ci-robot@users.noreply.github.com
4a46efb70701ee00028723ecb137e401d83be4f4|2020-11-24T07:45:19Z|vendor: update cAdvisor to v0.38.5|David Porter|david@porter.me
```

***Note:***

1.Make sure you have installed [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download) to get output in the desired format and parse json key as per your requirement.

2.Make sure to update the Git Repo Url in "curl" command.